# ParamConverter Attribute null

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with my param converter.

Those are my routing:

***CrmBundle routing.yml:***

```
crm_partner:
    resource: "@PartnerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{urlname}
```

***PartnerBundle routing.yml:***

```
crm_partner_dashboard:
    path:     /dashboard
    defaults: { _controller: PartnerBundle:Default:dashboard }
```

***PartnerBundle DefautController:***

```
    /*
     * @ParamConverter("department", options={"mapping":{"urlname":"urlName"}})
     */
    public function dashboardAction(Department $department)
    {
        ...        
    }
```

And this is my error:

```
Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "department".
```

and this my request attribute....

```
_controller      
         "PartnerBundle\Controller\DefaultController::dashboardAction"
_firewall_context           "security.firewall.map.context.main"
_locale                     "fr"
_route                      "crm_partner_dashboard"
_route_params               "urlname" => "shbyjm-europe-1"
                            "_locale" => "fr"
urlname                     "shbyjm-europe-1"
```

Do you have an explanation for that?

Best regards

Comment: What was your request URI? `/something/shbyjm-europe-1/dashboard`?

Comment: /crm/shbyjm-europe-1/dashboard

Comment: Are you possibly just missing the placeholder in the URL route itself, something like `department/{urlName}`???

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add class there. That's your issue. Check my code.

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Post $post
     * @ParamConverter("post", class="AppBundle\Entity\Post")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showAction(Post $post): Response
    {
        if (!isset($post)) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post with the provided route not found!');
        }
        return $this->render(
            '@App/pages/post.html.twig',
            [
                'post' => $post
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

So it's throwing you error, that it can't guess, because you doesn't pass the class **full namespaced name.**

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help.

To make my code successfull, i created my own ParamConverter and now it works perfectly.

I think that the problem was that my param is in the first level of my routing and was not correctly use or find.

Anyway, thanks again